# Guessing algorithm does not seem to work, guessing number by Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am struggling with some simple algorithm which should make python guess the given number in as few guesses as possible. It seems to be running but it is extremely slow. What am I doing wrong. I have read several topics already concerning this problem, but can't find a solution. I am a beginner programmer, so any tips are welcome.

```
min = 1
max = 50

number = int(input(("please choose a number between 1 and 50: ")))

total = 0
guessed = 0

while guessed != 1:
    guess = int((min+max)/2)
    total += 1 

    if guess == number:
        print("The number has been found in ",total," guesses!")
        guessed = 1
    elif guess > number:
        min = guess + 1
    elif guess < number:
        max = guess - 1
```

Thanks

ps. I am aware the program does not check for wrong input ;)

Comment: suggestion: use boolean for guessed?

Comment: Oh my, this is terrible. the > and < should be the other way around. Quite embarrassing. Can be closed!

Comment: yepp, just turn the logic around, otherwise you will end up in guessing `50` or whatever for eternity. But i have one hint concerning your usage of `print("The number has been found in ",total," guesses!")` which can be written like: `print("The number has been found in %s guesses!" % total)` which gives you a nicer output. if you want to pass more than one value, then the syntax is: `print("The number %s has been found in %s guesses!" % (guess, total))`

Comment: Thnx for the response! It's well appreciated

Comment: @hexereisoftware - It might be better to recommend the `.format(...)` method than the `%` operator, `%` is on it's way out.

Comment: @will defiantly! as i already told Padraic, i am "old school" and like the `%` because it reads well. For debugging it is fine, but for having full control over your output and avoiding type errors, the `.format()` function is the way to go. Thanks will :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is backwards.  You want to *lower* the `max` when you guess too high and *raise* the `min` when you guess too low.  Try this:

```
if guess == number:
    print("The number has been found in ",total," guesses!")
    guessed = 1
elif guess > number:
    max = guess - 1
elif guess < number:
    min = guess + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from having the logic backwards, you should not be using min and max as variable names. They are python functions. You can also use while True and break as soon as the number is guessed.

```
while True:
    guess = (mn + mx) // 2
    total += 1
    if guess == number:
        print("The number has been found in {} guesses!".format(total))
        break
    elif guess < number:
        mn = guess
    elif guess > number:
        mx = guess
```

You will also see by not adding or subtracting 1 from guess this will find the number in less steps.

Comment: well, it uses a `while True:` and `break` construct, which is probably wiser then using a variable `guessed` - and the comment about naming conventions is wise too. so no down vote please :)

Comment: nice that you added the `.format(total)` solution, better output :) but i prefer the `"" % (var)` syntax: `print("The number has been found in %s guesses!" % total)`

Comment: @hexereisoftware, I have pretty much always used str.format  with python, just more feature full than the old style printf and less prone to typos!

Comment: true, i am old school and just use the printf style for simple or debug output because it types fast and reads well. for output in file or if i need exact influence on output, nothing goes by the `.format()` version

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

print('choose a number in your brain and if guess is true enter y else any key choose time of guess: ')

print("define the range (A,B) :")
A = int(input("A: "))
B = int(input("B: "))
time = int(input("time:"))

while time != 0:
    ran = randint(A, B)
    inp = input(f"is this {ran} ?")
    time -= 1
    if inp == "y":
        print("bla bla bla python wins!")
        break
    print("NOPE!")
    if time == 0:
        print("computer game over!")
        break
```

Comment: can you please explain how above code helps to achieve OP's `simple algorithm which should make python guess the given number in as few guesses as possible`, I think in worst case it will take B number of time to guess the correct number.